# Border Layout with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border-layout

I'm trying to use a slider with some JLabels to make a simple program that takes the radius from the slider and outputs to labels the circumference and diameter. My problem is I can't seem to figure out how to layout the labels with border layout. The slider will show up just fine but I want to be able to layout the labels in a row on the left side in a row of labels.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

public class Slider extends JFrame {

private final JSlider radiusJSlider;
private final JLabel radius;
private final JLabel diameter;


public Slider() {
    super("Slider Demo");
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    radius = new JLabel("radius");
    diameter = new JLabel("diameter");

    radiusJSlider
            = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 200, 10);
    radiusJSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10); // create tick every 10
    radiusJSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    radiusJSlider.setPaintLabels(true);// paint ticks on slider

radiusJSlider.setLabelTable(radiusJSlider.createStandardLabels(10));
    //JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    //panel.add(diameter, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );

    labels.add(radius);
    labels.add(diameter);

    add(radiusJSlider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //add(radius, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //add(diameter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    layout.addLayoutComponent(labels, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    radiusJSlider.addChangeListener(
            new ChangeListener() // anonymous inner class
    {
        // handle change in slider value
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int results;
            int diameterResults;

            results = radiusJSlider.getValue();
            diameterResults = results * 2;

            radius.setText(String.format("radius: %2d", radiusJSlider.getValue()));
            diameter.setText(String.format("diameter: %2d", diameterResults));
        }
    }
    );

}

}
```

Comment: The BorderLayout is created but doesn't seem to be added to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing this `layout.addLayoutComponent(labels, BorderLayout.CENTER);`, this isn't how you should interact with a layout manager

Since `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, there's no need to create a new one, instead, just do the same thing you did with the slider, add the panel to the container

```
add(labels); // BorderLayout.CENTER is the default position
```

Comment: how would I go about lining up the labels in a vertical row versus horizontal?

Comment: Have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)